# Docker library/base not found?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I'm new to docker then I tried this command to pull 'docker pull base' but an error of `FATA[0008] Error: image library/base:latest not found`

anyone knows this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The image "[`library/ubuntu/`](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/library/ubuntu/)" mentions:

> General use Ubuntu base image.
>   Tags available are “`latest`” (equivalent to the tags “`precise`” and “12.04”), “`saucy`” (“13.10”), “`raring`” (“13.04”), “`quantel`” (“12.10”), and “`lucid`” (“10.04”).
>   The “latest” tag is equivalent to the most recent Long Term Support (LTS) release of Ubuntu.
>
> **This image replaces the deprecated “`base`” image**.

So if you were trying to pull the latest ubuntu image, a `git pull ubuntu:latest` should work.